# List datatype in Object view

Tags: email, leads

I want to do this:

I have some leads.

I have some email campaigns.

I want to have some kind of generic section below a lead where I show information about email campaigns ONLY IN WHICH THEY WERE TARGETED. I.e. if a new lead was added after this campaign, then I don't include any black fields with their data.

At the moment, before each email campaign, we create a new set of fields for all leads such as: Campagn_Link_Clicked, Campaign_Email_Sent (i.e. a list of their recorded actions).

I would like some kind of list within the lead where "Email Campaign Objects" are inserted, each with info about a particular campaign. I can then search to see who participated in this campaign and then also on their actions associated to it.

Is there any way this can be done? Because at this rate, we will be adding fields with every campaign indefinitely.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about the Campaign Member object. Does this not do what you need?

Comment: Why aren't you using the Campaign Member object for this purpose?
EDIT: seems @Jeremy Nottingham was half a minute quicker than me:-)

Comment: Potentially, please expand :-)

Comment: this isn't a bad introduction - http://www.shellblack.com/whiteboard/overview-and-creating-a-campaign/ (and part 2).  The SFDC `Campaign` and `CampaignMember` objects are your friends here.  I can't really think of any reason to use custom solution unless you had extremely sophisticated requirements. Both objects can be extended with custom fields and have picklists tailored; There is an import wizard that is very handy. One lead can be part of many campaigns. Lead conversion to Oppo enables ROI reporting

Comment: OK great, no one wants to leave an answer?

Comment: If I am tracking whether an email was delivered myself, how do I store statistics on this?